# c++ use a global variable from a program in a shared library

Tags: c++, global-variables, shared-libraries

I have created a program that can load different shared libraries (problem1.so, problem2.so, etc...). In this program, I have a Config object used as a global variable. I would like to know how to share the global variable between my program and the shared libraries. For the moment, I've done this:

Config.hh

```
struct Config {
  Config();
  int test;
};
extern Config config;
```

Config.cpp

```
#include "Config.hh"
Config config;
Config::Config() : test(3) {} // set test to 3
```

Problem1.hh // partial main class of one of my shared libraries

```
#include "Config.hh"
class Problem {
  Problem();
};
```

Problem1.cpp // partial file

```
#include "Problem.hh"
Problem::Problem() {
   std::cout << config.test << std::endl; // print 0 and not 3
}
```

The problem is that the Problem constructor print 0 and not 3, as if my global variable (which perfectly works outside of the shared library) is reset in the shared library. Does someone know how to fix this ?

EDIT: The "Problem" object is not a global

Comment: Are you using a global `Problem` object?

Comment: Maybe a problem with the order of initialization of globals

Answer (score 0):

Guess you have the `Problem` object as a global object too, and defined in a different source file from `config`. Initialization of global objects goes through two phases, namely static initialization and dynamic initialization.

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables) (emphasis mine):

> **Static initialization**
>   ...
>   2) For all other non-local static and thread-local variables, Zero
>   initialization takes place. In practice, variables that are going to
>   be zero-initialized are placed in the .bss segment of the program
>   image, which occupies no space on disk, and is zeroed out by the OS
>   when loading the program.
>   ...
>   **Dynamic initialization**
>   ...
>   2) *Ordered dynamic initialization*, which applies to all other
>   non-local variables: within a single translation unit, these variables
>   are initialized in exact order their definitions appear in the source
>   code. **Initialization of static variables in different translation
>   units is indeterminately sequenced.** Initialization of thread-local
>   variables in different translation units is unsequenced.

So, in your case, before the `Config` and `Problem` constructors are called (which amounts to dynamic initialization), static initialization zero initializes `test` to be `0`. During the dynamic initialization phase, if `config` and your global `Problem` object are defined in separate `cpp` files (translation units), you can't tell whose constructor is invoked first. If the constructor of the `Problem` object is invoked first before that of `config`, then within the `Problem` constructor, you will see `test` being `0` as a result of static initialization.